# How to generate NDK toolchain from AOSP (Android Open Source Project 5.1.1_r30)

Tags: c++, android-ndk, ubuntu-16.04, ndk-build

I am trying to build a 3rd party c++ library for Android application. The android platform version is 5.1.1_r30. By following the guild http://source.android.com/source/building.html, the AOSP can be built successfully.

But the folder android_source/ndk/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/ only contains two project file config.mk and setup.mk.

How should I generate the ndk toolchain?

If I could use the standalone toolchain, which version should I use for AOSP 5.1.1_r30? Or I can just use the latest one (android-ndk-r12b-linux-x86_64)?

Thanks for your suggestions.

---

**Environment:**
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 
gcc 4.9.3 (by default it was 5.4 I switched to 4.9) 
g++ 4.9

AOSP: 5.1.1_r30

java version: openJDK 1.7
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac

Comment: It seems that the guild here http://clseto.mysinablog.com/index.php?op=ViewArticle&articleId=3480794 might be the answer. Verifying...

Comment: Do you just require a "standalone toolchain" per the build instructions for the 3rd party C++ library?